# Get which pressed by a incoming caller on Android

Tags: android

I was trying to make an android based voice response system (IVR) with a program. Please tell me how to get the keys pressed by the caller of an incoming call.

Suppose he press 1 I have to play a music. if he press 2 I have to play him a recorded message. like that. (like press 1 for English, Press 2 for French. like that)

One thing is for sure that we will get different key tones if he press different keys in his mobile, or land phone during the call.

Comment: What system are you using to run your phone system? For the avoidance of doubt, are you talking about something that does not run on the Android phone itself, but responds via the dialled call on the other side? If so, maybe you could look into Asterisk, which as I understand it is a software phone-system in a single package.